# What is the minimum number of collisions for photon required to lose all of its energy in an electron cloud?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

The electron cloud I refer to is a free electron cloud. Please help in this question. Is the answer infinite? If it is then it would take infinite time,  which it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand this question - what is the mechanism you allow for the photon to "lose" its energy by? Compton scattering? Pair production?

Answer (score 1):

As you know that electron loses its energy in scattering with free electron via Compton scattering and the change in wavelength of the photon can be written as

$\lambda'-\lambda=\frac{h}{m_ec}(1-\cos\theta)$

after some manipulation the above equation can be written as

$\Delta E_{photon}=\frac{2E_{photon}^2}{m_ec^2}(1-\cos\theta)$

(this equation is valid for small change in the energy of photon during the scattering event) you may find that with the decrease in photon energy the change in the phton energy reduces and you will never reach to a situation that the photon can loose all of its energy via scattering from free electrons.

Physically we can say that the momentum transfer from photon to electron reduces as the photon loses its energy (similar to the negligible momentum transfer during collision of two particles with largely different mass). This is the reason that while working with optical photons the Compton scattering changed into elastic Thomson scattering.

Hope this will clear your doubts

Comment: With a specific electron, things may be weird. But, with the electrons cloud $\theta$ is random and surely uniform. Perhaps it is possible to use 1/2 and build the sequence which converges to the elastic scaterring macro state after a mean number of collisions depending only of the original wavelenght.

Comment: @igael you are right one must use some average (i think $1/\sqrt2$ would be more appropriate) but this is just an illustration.

Comment: @jim as $E_{photon}$ decreases the ratio with rest mass energy decreases and if the value of $E_{photon}<m_0 c^2$ then the reduction of energy reduces appreciably and Compton scattering is converted in Thomson Scattering

Comment: I wonder if the formula of an electron inside an atom holds for a free electron : what is $\theta$ for a free electron ?

Comment: @Jim : the Compton scattering has always been quantized and relativistic

Comment: The question "The formula for Compton scattering is correct relativistically?" was rhetorical. Given that the formula is correct relativistically, if you have $E_{photon} \gt 0.5 m_ec^2$ then it appears that there is an angle for which $\Delta E_{photon} = E_{photon}$ is possible which means that the photon can lose all energy in one collision?

Comment: @jim Actually the assumption $\Delta E$ is small is used while deriving the energy equation from wavelength equation. I hope this will clarify the situation.